# regex to match/remove all CRLF between quotation marks that have at least one alphanum char before and after

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I need a regex to remove CRLF that fulfill all the following requirements:

1. Happen between double quotation marks ""
2. Have at least one alphanumeric char between the opening quotation mark and the CRLF
3. Have at least one alphanumeric char between the closing quotation mark and the CRLF
4. Must match all CRLF between the same set of quotation marks

Example (I write [CRLF] for demonstration purposes):

```
"1843","75 x 63 cm.","Bergamot","lb","Set of 6, 2022[CRLF]
On paper[CRLF]
(each)[CRLF]
Numbered","2022"[CRLF]
"20500","89 X 28 cm."
```

All [CRLF] should be matched and removed EXCEPT the last one, because there are no alphanum characters before and after.

I can work with VSCode, and Linux CLI.

Thank you

Comment: My non-working attempt: `(?<="[^"\n]*[a-zA-Z])[^"\n]*[\n\s](?=[^"\n]*[a-zA-Z][^"\n]*")`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283321/command-line-tool-for-easy-multiline-regex-search-and-replace should get you started.

Comment: @tink I would appreciate if you could elaborate why that q/a could get me started, please, thank you

Comment: Because most linux command line tools operate w/ regex per line, not multi line. The use of perl in the answer shows how to construct a multiline regex. You nust need to add a `"` at the beginning and a negative lookahead after the last `"`.  Alternatively you should be able to use the same regex w/ grep w/ the switched `-Pzo` if perl is not your thing.

Comment: Thanks @tink, the negative look-around gave me an idea to solve this in a much simpler way. I posted an answer to my own question that covers the provided case and all similar cases.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the comment by tink I approached the problem differently, using a negative look-ahead.

The following regex selects any newline that is NOT followed by a quotation mark.

```
\n(?!")
```

This matches all cases in the provided example.

As per my original question I used it in VSCode search and replace (with regex) dialog successfully.

Although I expected having to use `\r\n`, I actually used simply `\n` as described.